# How to get intended taste using baking powder instead of acid + baking soda?

Tags: baking, cake, baking-soda, baking-powder

A [coffee cake recipe](https://www.williams-sonoma.com/recipe/cranberry-sour-cream-coffee-cake-with-streusel-topping.html) calls for using sour cream and baking soda. I understand that [acid + baking soda](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/83440/baking-soda-as-a-substitute-for-baking-powder) is a leavening agent and you can use them as a substitute for baking powder. But I only have baking powder.

1. If I use baking powder instead, will the taste of the coffee cake be majorly affected? It won't have the sourness of the cream anymore, but how important is that in a coffee cake?
2. Can I add something else along with the baking powder so I can get something close to the intended original taste?

Comment: Related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7821/substitution-for-baking-soda-in-pancakes, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/68637/replacements-for-baking-soda-in-a-cake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use baking powder instead of baking soda in this recipe, you'll have an excess of acid.  That's not too bad (an excess of baking soda gives a soapy, bitter flavour).  The effect is likely to be as if your sour cream was slightly more sour. If you wish to tone that effect down you could  replace a small amount of your sour cream with cream or even milk.

The rise may be slightly affected but this should be minor; with or without the acid in the baking powder you're limited by the alkaline component. Baking powder is usally [double-acting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baking_powder) meaning some of the reaction is delayed until it gets hot. Sour cream plus baking soda is likely to start reacting immediately, so substituting the other way would be worse.